# Prevent keyup event from firing when input box selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event that I want to fire whenever <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is pressed, with the exception of when in an input field.

Specifically, I'm worried about `<input id='nameInput' type='text'>` that I dynamically create when I click in a div and remove `onchange`/`onblur`. That's why I tried checking `if( !$('#nameInput') )`, but `$('#nameInput')` is a jQuery object, so its boolean value is always `true` (and hence `!$('#nameInput') == false`).

```
$(window).bind('keyup',
  function(e) { 
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 32 || code == 82){
      if( !$('#nameInput') ){
        roll();
      }
    }
  }
);
```

I have a solution that utilizes a global boolean variable getting set in onfocus of the input field, but I'd like a solution that doesn't require a global variable if it's possible.

Is there a way to determine what element currently has focus?

Comment: thanks @Alexey, wasn't sure how to make those look all pretty like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.activeElement) to know wich element currently has focus.

```
if (!$(document.activeElement).is('input, textarea')) {
    roll();
}
```

You could also make use of the `:focus` selector.

```
if (!$(':focus').is('input, textarea')) { 
    roll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, I went with:
    var active = $(document.activeElement);
    if(active[0] === $('#nameInput')[0]){
      return;
    }
    roll();

Comment: @mduleone, You did not want the opposite? When the `nameInput` is not focused, then roll? Also, you can use `$(document.activeElement).is('#nameInput')`